# What is the difference between using __exact and Exact()?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, searchqueryset

I am using Solr search for Django application using Haystack. In order to get more precise result, I had to change the search query to perform exact search -

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet, SQ
from haystack.inputs import Exact

....
query = SQ(tags_indexed=Exact(val.lower()))
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(
                    SampleModel).filter(query)
...
```

Now, other way you can do the exact search as mentioned in some documentation is -

```
query = SQ(tags_indexed__exact=val.lower())
```

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SQ`](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/__init__.py#L412) inherits from django's `Q` object and will be using djangos [`exact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exact) field lookup.

[`Exact`](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/inputs.py#L63) is a Haystack class that does its own thing. (but most likely ends up at the same query)

[The docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/inputtypes.html#haystack.inputs.Exact) state that they are equivalent so it doesn't make much of a difference which you use.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for pointing to the link and explanation. The reason why I ask is locally I use whoosh with Haystack and it doesn't give the same result when using __exact vs Exact(). with whoosh using Exact() gives correct result.